# "spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 400, code:-1" when using recommendations() from spotipy API

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to build a program with spotipy that will create a custom spotify playlist.
I succeeded to get three lists with the current_user_recently_played() function that contain the recently played genres, artists and tracks. according to that three lists i'm trying to use the **spotipy.client.Spotify.recommendations** in order to get recommendations by those three parameters. [the func description from the spotipy documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rGoi.png)

this is the code:

```
 recommendations = spotify.recommendations(seed_artists=artists, seed_genres=genres, seed_tracks=tracks)
```

when:

```
artists = ['5eAWCfyUhZtHHtBdNk56l1', '6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao', '0epOFNiUfyON9EYx7Tpr6V']   
tracks = ['31RTFPrB7wmYBhlkM2ILXG', '3nlGByvetDcS1uomAoiBmy', '55N8cxpE1QDoeaaNqUnoZ2']
genres = ['rock', 'metal', 'punk', 'grunge', 'pop']
```

When i'm runing the code I get this error:

```
HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations returned 400 due to invalid request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 172, in _internal_call
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\itama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations?limit=20&seed_artists=5eAWCfyUhZtHHtBdNk56l1%2C6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao%2C0epOFNiUfyON9EYx7Tpr6V%2C7oPftvlwr6VrsViSDV7fJY&seed_genres=rock%2Cmetal%2Cpunk%2Cgrunge&seed_tracks=31RTFPrB7wmYBhlkM2ILXG%2C3nlGByvetDcS1uomAoiBmy%2C55N8cxpE1QDoeaaNqUnoZ2%2C3LRJbFT9rKoKv4aW7PuBJC

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itama\Desktop\recommendation_playlist.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(spotify.recommendations(seed_artists=artists[:4], seed_genres=genres[:4], seed_tracks=tracks[:4],))
  File "C:\Users\itama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 1219, in recommendations
    return self._get("recommendations", **params)
  File "C:\Users\itama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 207, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\itama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 187, in _internal_call
    headers=response.headers,
spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 400, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations?limit=20&seed_artists=5eAWCfyUhZtHHtBdNk56l1%2C6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao%2C0epOFNiUfyON9EYx7Tpr6V%2C7oPftvlwr6VrsViSDV7fJY&seed_genres=rock%2Cmetal%2Cpunk%2Cgrunge&seed_tracks=31RTFPrB7wmYBhlkM2ILXG%2C3nlGByvetDcS1uomAoiBmy%2C55N8cxpE1QDoeaaNqUnoZ2%2C3LRJbFT9rKoKv4aW7PuBJC:
 invalid request
```

---

any way to solve this? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured that out... you can't use more than five seeds.